# Sharetribe sub listing of a listing

Tags: sharetribe

## Does anyone know how to add a sub listing of a current listing? Please help.

I was trying to create a sub listing under a listing, does anyone have an idea how to make it? And where should i store the data.

Should I store it under the current listing on something like the private data or store as a sibling of the current listing?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of information most likely should be store in listing [public data](https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/references/extended-data/#public-data). The sub-listing information can then be used to implement pricing by leveraging Flex's recently updated [pricing functionality](https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/background/pricing/).

See [the Customize pricing article](https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/cookbook-payments/customize-pricing/) in the Flex docs site for an example of a listing add-on.